# No sound in ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: sound, 18.04, pulseaudio, alsa

[image: Sound Settings]

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 . My sound ouput shows two output one is the Multichannel Output and other is analog output but still there is no sound.

**Updated :**

I try `pacmd`

[image: output]

and the output say :

[image: Ouput of List-sinks]

after muting master volumes using sudo iecset audio on
output says

[image: this]

Comment: did you try install `pulseaudio` and `pavucontrol` sir?

Comment: how should i do that?

Comment: try with `apt-get install pulseaudio* pavucontrol* `

Comment: i have executed that command what next sir?

Comment: what that output said? i don't know where your issue exactly.

Comment: it just installed those packages

Comment: try check your audio settings with `pacmd` and type `list-sinks` , what that output said? please edit your queestion with that output.

Comment: Sir i have added the outuput you can check

Comment: try with `sudo alsa force-reload` and `sudo init 6`

Comment: still no sound sir

Comment: did you sure muting the master volumes?

Comment: couldn't get you sir

Comment: to mute try `sudo iecset audio on`

Comment: i have added the output you can check

Comment: make sure your master volumes is on like [this](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ezTvD5RfaQinZFd_NDn21MX3r6YkJl6b) .

Comment: master volume is on sir

Comment: did you try "test speaker" on at audio settings using "analog output" ?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem at your Multichannel Output haven't been to configuration completely.

before pulseaudio read from the system-wide file, you need copying `/etc/pulse/default.pa` to `.config/pulse/default.pa`. and edit your  `.config/pulse/default.pa` with adding following :

```
load-module module-remap-sink sink_name=headphones remix=no master=alsa_output.pci-0000_00_03.0.stereo-fallback channels=2 master_channel_map=front-left,front-right channel_map=front-left,front-right sink_properties=device.description=Headphones
load-module module-remap-sink sink_name=speakers remix=no master=alsa_output.pci-0000_00_03.0.stereo-fallback channels=2 master_channel_map=rear-left,rear-right   channel_map=front-left,front-right sink_properties=device.description=Speakers

update-sink-proplist 0 device.description="Both"

update-sink-input-proplist 0 media.name="Headphones"
update-sink-input-proplist 1 media.name="Speakers"
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: this work for me!